# Query returns ODBC error "too few arguments" in a not-prepared statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, odbc

I'm trying to run this code from the ASP.Net code:

```cs
string strupdate = "Insert into registers(user, module, event_type)" +
    "values (" +
    "'" + user + "'," +
    "'" + event + "'," +
    "'" + source + "');";

/* connSQL it's the ODBC connection type: System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection */
connSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The query results into the following:

```sql
Insert into registers(user, module, event_type)values('user01','message','control');
```

Running this query from *psql* works perfectly fine, but running from the web returns the ODBC 07002 error with the following message: The # of binded parameters < the # of parameter markers

Comment: **Use parameters** and don't concatenate sql, otherwise you are prone to sql injection... You also wouldn't have the issue you are experiencing; `"'" + event + ","` should be `"'" + event + "',"` missing tick.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the `"'" + event + "," +` code, it should be `"'" + event + "'," +`.

i.e., ending single quote was missed in the second parameter value.

**Note:** Your code is possible for SQL Injection attack. Please convert the code with parameterised values.